# Matlab, expanding, simultaneous equation solving for a control system

Tags: matlab

I have this code in matlab

```
syms L1 L0 P1 P0 s
L = expand(s*(s^2+L1*s+L0)*(s-75)+1400*(P1*s+P0))
R = expand((s+75)*(s+150)^3)
```

I want to solve for `P1`, `P0`, `L1` and `L0`

`L = R`

```
1400*P0 - 75*L0*s + 1400*P1*s + L0*s^2 - 75*L1*s^2 + L1*s^3 - 75*s^3 + s^4 = s^4 + 525*s^3 + 101250*s^2 + 8437500*s + 253125000
```

by observation:

```
1400*P0 = 253125000
```

ETC...

How do i pull simultaneous equations from `L=R` in Matlab and automatically solve for each variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write the equation as `L-R=0`, then do something like `C=coeffs(L-R,s)`. Then, something like the following code might solve the equations:

```
for i=1:length(C)
    sol(i)=solve(C(i));
end
```

but it may be difficult to work out which element of `sol` refers to which variable. But if you are going to look at the output as the code runs it should be pretty obvious I'd imagine.